# Pass a php variable through the URL in the action part of a HTML form

Tags: php, html, variables, url

I have the following html form in one of my php files:

```
<form action="reply.php?id=$id" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

When this form is submitted I want to pass the $id variable from this file into my reply file.

In my reply file I have used the following get method but all that is stored in the $queryid variable is $id instead of the int value that it should be.

```
$queryid = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

I realise it's probably something simple I am missing but I just can't seem to work it out.

Comment: You have to show more of your HTML, but I guess that you have to echo original `$id` inside HTML using php tags: `<form action="reply.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">`

Comment: That's all I was missing! Thank you. Don't know how I missed that

Answer (score 2):

You need to echo the ID in php right, now you are literally assigning the Id to "$id"

Use this:

```
<form action="reply.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```

But I would recommend just inserting the ID as a hidden input and sending it with the rest of the post data.

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" name="id"> </input>
```

Comment: Thanks, I only had the `method="post"` missing, once I put that in, boom!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $queryid = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
?>
<form action="reply.php?id=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($queryid); ?>" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
```